# Does temporarily removing the fan from the heatsink void AMD’s warranty?

Tags: fan, cooling, heatsink, warranty

I needed to RMA my newly-bought motherboard, so that meant removing the CPU and HSF. Now i need to clean the remnants of thermal goop from the CPU and heatsink in order to put the new one afterward, but it will be much easier for me to clean the heatsink if i remove the fan first.

The fan is fastened to the heatsink with 4 “+” screws that do not seem to be protected with any tamper-evident seals. Will temporarily removing it to clean the heatsink void my warranty on the CPU if i reattach everything as it were afterward?

Comment: No, it will not, provided it does not appear to have been tampered with.

Comment: @geewee source?

Comment: common sense. They don't use special device to check the seal's integrity -- they just eyeball them.

Comment: Technically speaking, the fan, the heat sink with the CPU are user serviceable parts and are allowed to be removed for regular maintenance. So that does not void any kind of warranty